# "error: too few arguments to function 'exit'"?? I've included the stdlib.h too. Why is this showing?

Tags: c

```text
Windows PowerShe11 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Try the new cross-platform PowerShe11 https://aka.ms/pscore6 

PS C:\Users\Sourabh\Desktop\C assignnt> gcc calc.c 
calc.c: In function 'main': 
calc.c:30:9: error: too few arguments to function 'exit'
         exit(); 
         ^~~~
In file included from calc.c:2:0: 
c:\mingw\include\stdlib.h:489:39: note: declared here 
_CRTIMP __cdecl _MINGW_NOTHROW  void exit (int) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                     ^~~~
PS C:\Users\Sourabh\Desktop\C assignnt>
```

Can someone help and explain in a simple way? Thank you.

Comment: The error message, `void exit (int)`, is telling you that "exit()" needs an "int" argument for the error code.  Your "switch" block has "exit()" (no argument).  Add an integer number (e.g. "exit(1)") to fix the compile error.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Thank you:) and I'll take care not to post images.

Answer (score 5):

The `exit` function takes one parameter, the exit status code.

This will exit with the status 0, which means “success”

```
exit(0);
```

Other status codes, from 1-255, usually indicate that the program failed. It is up to you to define the exit status for your program, but 0=“success”, 1=“failure”, 2=“incorrect program arguments” is a common convention.

Comment: Note that the exit codes are not completely standardised, but there exists `sysexits.h` which is supported by quite a few platforms.

Comment: @Cheatah: I do not recommend `<sysexits.h>` because it goes against convention. Some style guides explicitly discourage `<sysexits.h>`.

Comment: @Cheatah in addition to what Dietrich Epp said you can also use the macros `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` from `<stdlib.h>`